# XML loading very slow with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I have the following code:

```
<?php
include "convert/xmlToArray.php";

$query_string = $_GET['query_string'];

if ($query_string == "") {
    $query_string = "travel";
}

$completeurl = "http://my_site";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);

$arrayData = xmlToArray($xml);

echo json_encode($arrayData);
?>
```

There is another page that fetches theses results with JavaScript and displays it to the user.

The page takes more than 10 seconds to fetch the results and display them.

Does anyone have any idea on how to make it load faster? Is there a client based solution?

Thanks

Comment: You should start out by profiling the different calls just to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: How would I do that? What do you mean?

Comment: how much time is required by "simplexml_load_file($completeurl);" ?

Comment: Just echo the current time before you start each operation that can potentially be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Save all your data to file php file. For example if you want get array you can simply include a file and use data. Its simply way to using php faster.